# Resizing window of sfml app

Tags: c++, resize, sfml

I'm new in SFML, now I have an experience in game programming. In my code I have diffirent objects with its coordinates. Now I hardcode all x and y for fixed resolution. The question is how ti code it correctly? I mean how to code so, that if player will resize game window, all objects will be resized too?

Thanks in advance

Up

Answer (score 3):

The basic idea of what you need to do is apply a transform to drawing calls.

Come up with a definite size you want your "virtual" display to be, say 640 by 480. In your main window loop, you should be polling for events; the event we're looking for is the sf::Event with type SizeEvent. When the window is resized, this event will be called and you will get the new X/Y resolution of the display area.

When you process that event, you will need to generate some new numbers based on how much you have to scale your drawing functions. For example, if my "target" or "virtual" display is 640 by 480 and the window is sized to 1600 by 960, then I will look at my current aspect ratio and decide how much I can scale by. For the X, 1600/640 is a factor of 250%, but my Y is only 960/480 for 200%. In this case, I would use a factor of 2 to scale up the size, and then put 160 pixel black bars on the left and right sides (that way I keep the same aspect ratio).

AFAIK, SFML doesn't actually have a global matrix you can apply transforms to - I could very well be wrong. However, what you may have to do is offset the position of every sprite you draw by 160 pixels on the X axis and then scale by a factor of 2.0. You may also want to draw black rectangles on the left and right side of the screen right before Window.display to make sure nothing "clips" off the edges.

Sorry I didn't give any actual code - the API doc is your friend, and especially look at setScale(), setPositition(), and setTransform() on [this](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.2/classsf_1_1Sprite.php) page.

Comment: Thanks a lot! May be do you know where can I read about details of realization? I think, it's not very good to resize every object "handly", may be is it easier to make an abstract class for all objects, where I can realize some methods? Any link, where can I read about it, will be enough.

Comment: Near the bottom of [link](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/graphics-transform.php), it points out that all objects are transformed relative to their parent. So probably the best approach is to have a single parent object that contains all the rest of your game objects. Then if you resize that object, everything else will be adjusted automatically.